# Issues with manual update from 7.77 to 7.78 on cPanel with PHP 7.4

Tags: updating

I have been manually been doing Drupal 7 and 8 updates on cPanel for many years. I carefully read what files need to be updated and what files need to stay.

Recently, there was an update to PHP 7.4. I cannot anymore manually update using Filezilla. I only get a generic server error, which doesn't say exactly what happened.

Has something changed in Drupal to cause this to happen? I really do not think it is a cPanel's issue.

Comment: Instead of guessing that is Drupal based on a hunch, check the logs to get something more than a generic server error.  Once you get the real error, you can google it and find a solution.

Comment: Welcome on Drupal Answers! It's more probable that something didn't change on Drupal 7, such as the compatibility with Drupal 7.4. Usually, a 503 error means a PHP error, but it could be a different server issue. Since it happened after a PHP update/upgrade, I would bet on that. As @PatrickKenny said, what is in the server/Drupal log is more descriptive and can tell you what happened, or at least be more helpful when searching for a fix.

Comment: Thank you @kiamlaluno. I appreciate your answer. I did try and turn the PHP back. It did not help. I can try it again. Perhaps, I will turn it back and wait a day or too for updates. The logs have not been helpful. Stay tuned.